# Tokenize path using JavaScript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to tokenize path to extract path variables using regexp with JavaScript.

I have have one expression that gives the template of the path to allow to define variable parts. Something like this: `/path/{val1}/rr/{val2}`, `/path/{val1}/rr/test1{val2}` or `/path/{val1}/rr/test1({val2})`.

I would like to extract values of variable parts of paths like this: `/path/myval1/rr/myval2`, `/path/myval1/rr/test1myval2` or `/path/myval1/rr/test1(myval2)`. To obtain something like this:

```
{
  var1: 'myvar1',
  var2: 'myvar2'
}
```

I try to use the following regexp to get tokens from the path template:

```
(^(\{{1})[\w\/]+(\}{1})$)|([!\{!\}\w]+)
```

Using that, I have almost what I need. For example for template path `/path/{val1}/rr/test1({val2})`, I have the following tokens:

```
path
{var1}
rr
test1
{val2}
```

But I would like to have:

```
/path/
{var1}
/rr/
/test1(
{val2}
)
```

I think I missed something but I can't find out what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
/\/?[^{\/]*\/?|{[^}]*}/g
```